youtube api "invallid filter parameter" error when requesting on large amount of videos
I am attempting to extract some data from all videos on a youtube channel (2055 videos). I have stored each video ID in video_ids[] and am sending a request for data regarding all 2055 in the following code:
all_video_data = []

request = youtube.videos().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        id=video_ids
    )
response = request.execute()

for video in response['items']:
    data_keep = {'snippet': ['channelTitle', 'title', 'publishedAt'],
                 'statistics': ['viewCount', 'likeCount', 'commentCount'],
                 'contentDetails': ['duration']
                }
    video_data = {}
    video_data['video_id'] = video['id']

    for k in data_keep.keys():
        for v in data_keep[k]:
            video_data[v] = video[k][v]

    all_video_data.append(video_data)

ERROR:
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 7
      1 all_video_data = []
      3 request = youtube.videos().list(
      4         part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
      5         id=video_ids[0:999]
      6     )
----> 7 response = request.execute()
      9 for video in response['items']:
     10     data_keep = {'snippet': ['channelTitle', 'title', 'publishedAt'],
     11                  'statistics': ['viewCount', 'likeCount', 'commentCount'],
     12                  'contentDetails': ['duration']
     13                 }

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py:130, in positional.<locals>.positional_decorator.<locals>.positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    128     elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    129         logger.warning(message)
--> 130 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py:938, in HttpRequest.execute(self, http, num_retries)
    936     callback(resp)
    937 if resp.status >= 300:
--> 938     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    939 return self.postproc(resp, content)

HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos returned "The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.". Details: "[{'message': 'The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.', 'domain': 'youtube.parameter', 'reason': 'invalidFilters', 'location': 'parameters.', 'locationType': 'other'}]">

I'm aware that the error is in my request, not sure how to fix.
tried moving around variables/names, tried doing a separate request for each video (awful), tried banging my head against a wall.

Well, YouTube probably doesn't like when people are requesting too large amounts of videos.

The limit per YouTube Data API v3 Videos: list endpoint HTTPS request is 50 ids of videos.

For reference: you asked a very similar Stack Overflow question 79024863.
